# Postgres user sees all schemas/tables

Tags: postgresql

When I create a new user for the database without any rights, this new user can still see all the schemas/tables etc. He can't access them, but he still sees them. I would like to revoke these privileges, but do not know how.

This is how I created the user:

```
CREATE USER wouter_test WITH PASSWORD 'wouter_test'
   NOSUPERUSER NOCREATEDB NOCREATEROLE NOCREATEUSER INHERIT;
```

based on this post I thought it may have to do with rights that users have to the public schema and the information the public schema contains: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/98892/minimal-grants-for-readonly-single-table-access-on-postgresql

Based on the wikisite: https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Shared_Database_Hosting
I used this command

```
REVOKE ALL ON SCHEMA public FROM wouter_test;
```

It did not work. The following did not seem to work either (to prevent the user from seeing and accessing a database called `klm`)

```
REVOKE connect ON DATABASE klm FROM wouter_test;
```

But still the user, in PGAdmin, can see all the databases, schemas and tables (including `klm`).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The DBA answer you linked talks about the `PUBLIC` **role**, not about the `public` **schema**. (Technically it mentions the schema too, but only says that it's usually not used, so it can be dropped altogether, instead of revoking/granting rights on it.)

Comment: Do you suggest I should revoke the public role, because the public role allows users to see the database structure?

Comment: If you want to manage rights for users/roles who are not created yet: yes, you typically want to grant/revoke on `PUBLIC` (but note that `PUBLIC` also covers already created users too).

Comment: Thank you. I am a little bit worried though what the consequences will be when I revoke on public. How does it affect already created users?

Comment: It will affect them too. As I said, every role is member of `PUBLIC`: newly created ones as well as old ones. `GRANT` for those you want to keep permissions before `REVOKE` from `PUBLIC`.

Answer (score 2):

You can `REVOKE ... FROM PUBLIC` to forbid all users to *use* an object, but you cannot keep the user from *seeing* the objects that way.

You can experiment with revoking privileges on system catalog tables like this:

```
REVOKE SELECT ON pg_catalog.pg_class FROM PUBLIC;
```

which will keep people from seeing the tables in the database.

This should keep the database functional, but it will cause errors in client programs like `psql` that expect to be able to read from these tables.